# Put scroll bar at the end of div tag

Tags: html, css, html-table, scrollbar

I am having three tables in side a div (MainDiv) with max-width:200px and max-height: 400px
And i BodyDiv with auto size and max-height: 300px.

I need a scroll in X direction in (MainDiv) And a scroll in Y direction of BodyDiv.
So that from MainDiv scroll I can scroll all three tables.

But it shows only three columns of BodyDiv and puts a scroll bar at 200px position. I need this scroll at the end of BodyDiv.

Here is my code:

### Code

```
<div id="MainDiv" style="max-width:200px;max-height: 400px;overflow-X: auto;overflow-Y: hidden;">
<table style="background-color:Fuchsia;width:100%;">
    <tr >
        <td class="Cell">
            column1
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column2
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column3
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column4
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column5
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="BodyDiv" style="max-height: 300px;overflow-Y: visible;overflow-X: hidden;">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_odd">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tr_even">
            <td class="Cell">
                column1
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column2
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column3
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column4
            </td>
            <td class="Cell">
                column5
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table style="background-color:Fuchsia;width:100%;">
    <tr >
        <td class="Cell">
            column1
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column2
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column3
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column4
        </td>
        <td class="Cell">
            column5
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm definitely not removing the extra spaces you have put there. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by adding the fixed width of inner div (BodyDiv) tag.
It puts scroll bar at the end of div.
And when we scroll Main Div it scrolls all three tables.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing what browser you are seeing the issue in would help. It looks mostly fine to me in Chrome.

Having both divs set to a max-height of 400px you are overloading the size of the outer div (height of first table + height of middle table + height of last table will always be greater than 400px when the middle table is allowed to expand to 400px), so the bottom table will be "pushed" out of the viewable area of the outer div.

Comment: Sorry i were made a mistake in my question.
My main div has a fixed width of 200px but my inner div has auto width size.
But when the size of my inner div increases it puts a scroll bar at 200px position (Fixed width of Main div) and hides the rest of columns.I just need to put this scroll at the end of inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the containing DIV should have overflow-X:hidden; overflow-Y:auto not the other way around?

You'll also need to give the container DIV a little more height to fit all three DIVs inside.

Comment: Yes i will.
I need a scroll in X direction in main div.And a scroll in Y direction in my inner div.So when we scroll main div scroll bar it scroll all three tables.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm afraid I'm not quite clear what you want to achieve, but at the moment as soon as the middle div is populated it pushes the bottom div out of the visible area as you have overflow-y:hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying your BodyDiv to be 100% width. This will mean that (including the scrollbar when present) it will only ever be 100% of the width of its parent (MainDiv at 200px wide).

The only way you can make BodyDiv larger than its parent is to use fixed width values, which may also cause you some issues because different browsers have slightly different scrollbar widths.

Comment: Thanks for your rpl.
I am changing width of child div at run time according to the header and footer table width ant it works.